# Deserialize Retrofit2 response into JSON without Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, retrofit2

I am calling an API using Retrofit2 that is giving me a large and complicated response. This was fine since all I needed to do was deserialize the response into a String and then put it on an activeMQ.

However, now I would like to add two more Json attributes to the complicated response so that it looks like the following:

`{
  "event": "some event",
  "link": "some link",
  "details": {complicated response ...}
}`

How do I deserialize a response as a Json (javax.json.Json), so then I can build onto it as a JsonObject with the new attributes, and then a String?

The JacksonConverterFactory forces me to fit this complicated response into POJOs and I do not want to do that! Right now I am adding strings to the top of the response, but this is not an ideal solution.

Comment: Alternatively, If there is a better solution overall, I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your large and complicated response is in a string named `input`, you could perhaps do the following:

```
JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(input));
JsonObject response = reader.readObject();

JsonObject queueMessage =
    Json.createObjectBuilder()
        .add("event", "some event")
        .add("link", "some link")
        .add("details", response)
        .build();
```

Another approach, which uses Jackson and doesn't force you to deserialize the complicated response into a structure of JSON-objects, is to use the [`@JsonRawValue`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonRawValue.html) annotation, which lets you mark a String field as already containing JSON that should be included verbatim during serialization.

This allows you to do something like:

```
public class MQMessage {
    public String event, link;

    @JsonRawValue
    public String details;
}


MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
message.event = "some event";
message.link = "Some link";
message.details = input;

String forMQ = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(message);
```

Be aware that Jackson doesn't do any verification that `details` actually contains valid JSON.